MySQL: Sumar el total de segundos trabajados por cada empleado, por meses en un año
Tengo dos tablas:
TABLA HORAS
CREATE TABLE `horas` (
  `turno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `empleado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `horaEntrada` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `horaSalida` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`turno`,`empleado`,`fecha`)
)
-- Ejemplo de consulta
+-------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| turno | empleado                | fecha      | horaEntrada | horaSalida |
+-------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+
|     0 | EMPLEADO 1              | 2024-05-14 | 08:10       | 16:34      |
|     1 | EMPLEADO 1              | 2024-05-14 | 19:14       | 22:23      |
|     0 | EMPLEADO 2              | 2024-05-14 | 05:30       | 14:03      |
|     0 | EMPLEADO 3              | 2024-05-14 | 13:56       | 18:45      |
+-------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+------------+

TABLA MENSUALES
CREATE TABLE `mensuales` (
  `empleado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `laboral` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vacaciones` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bajas` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acuerdo` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empleado`,`fecha`)
)
-- Ejemplo de consulta
+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| empleado            | fecha   | laboral     | direccion  | vacaciones | bajas | acuerdo |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| EMPLEADO 1          | 2024-04 | comentario  | comentario |      6.000 | 4.000 |  20.000 |
+---------------------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me devuelva los segundos trabajados por cada empleado por mes, incluyendo las vacaciones, bajas, horas del acuerdo, y los comentarios de laboral / dirección. Este es mi intento (modificación de esta respuesta):
SELECT horas.empleado, 
SUM(
    TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(
            STR_TO_DATE(
                CONCAT(
                        SUBSTRING(horas.fecha,1,8),
                        -- Si la hora salida < hora entrada = día siguiente
                        CAST(SUBSTRING(horas.fecha,9,10) AS SIGNED)+(1 * (CAST(SUBSTRING(horas.horaSalida,1,2) AS SIGNED) < CAST(SUBSTRING(horas.horaEntrada,1,2) AS SIGNED))),
                        " ",
                        horas.horaSalida,
                        "\:00"
                ),
            "%Y-%m-%d %H\:%i\:%s"),
            STR_TO_DATE(
                CONCAT(horas.fecha," ",horas.horaEntrada,"\:00"),"%Y-%m-%d %H\:%i\:%s"
            )
        )
    ) 
) as trabajadas, SUBSTRING(horas.fecha,1,7) as fecha, mensuales.direccion, mensuales.laboral, mensuales.vacaciones, mensuales.bajas, mensuales.acuerdo FROM horas LEFT JOIN mensuales ON mensuales.empleado = horas.empleado WHERE SUBSTRING(horas.fecha,1,4) = "2024" group by horas.empleado, fecha;

Quiero que devuelva (datos inventados, nada que ver con los ejemplos de consulta anteriores):
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| empleado                | trabajadas | fecha    | direccion  | direccion  | vacaciones | bajas | acuerdo |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| EMPLEADO 1              | 13500      | 2024-05  | algo       | asdasd     | 6.000      | 0.000 | 12.000  |
| EMPLEADO 1              | 23000      | 2024-06  | algo 2     | asdasd     | 0.000      | 0.000 | 12.000  |
| EMPLEADO 2              | 12300      | 2024-05  | qwerty     | asdasd     | 0.000      | 0.000 | 12.000  |
| EMPLEADO 3              | 10000      | 2024-05  | aaaaaa     | asdasd     | 0.000      | 0.000 | 12.000  |
+-------------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+

El problema de la consulta es que devuelve una cantidad de segundos irreal, o agrupa mal los meses:

Las horas que hizo en enero (la consulta me suma bien los segundos si en vez de todo el año, sólo saco un único mes):


Hay que hacerlo paso a paso. Primero queremos el trabajo sumado por trabajador y mes. Segundo queremos añadir los mensuales que ya son guardados por trabajador y mes.
En tu tabla horas las horas no son TIME sino VARCHAR. Entonces tenemos que convertirlos para usar las funcionas de TIME. Las fechas ya son DATE, entonces podemos usar las funciones y operadores de DATE.
    with
      trabajado as
      (
        select
          empleado, 
          date_format(fecha, '%Y-%m') as mes,
          sum(
            case when horaSalida >= horaEntrada then
              time_to_sec(timediff(cast(horaSalida as time), cast(horaEntrada as time))) 
            else -- de un día al otro: 24 horas (86400 segundos) menos la diferencia
              86400 - time_to_sec(timediff(cast(horaEntrada as time), cast(horaSalida as time))) 
            end
          ) as segundos_trabajados
        from horas
        where fecha >= date '2024-01-01' 
          and fecha <  date '2025-01-01'
        group by empleado, date_format(fecha, '%Y-%m')
      )
    select *
    from trabajado t
    left join mensuales on m.empleado = t.empleado and m.fecha = t.mes
    order by t.empleado, t.mes;

Para MySQL con versión inferior a 8.0:
    SELECT 
        t.trabajadas, t.empleado, t.mes, m.sandra, m.jose, m.vacaciones, m.bajas, m.acuerdo 
    FROM 
        (select 
            empleado, 
            date_format(fecha, '%Y-%m') as mes, 
            sum( 
                case when horaSalida >= horaEntrada 
                then time_to_sec(timediff(cast(horaSalida as time), cast(horaEntrada as time))) 
                else 86400 - time_to_sec(timediff(cast(horaEntrada as time), cast(horaSalida as time))) 
                end 
            ) as trabajadas 
        from 
            horas 
        where 
            SUBSTRING(horas.fecha,1,4) = '{fecha}' 
        group by empleado, date_format(fecha, '%Y-%m') 
    ) t 
    left join 
        mensuales m on m.empleado = t.empleado and m.fecha = t.mes order by t.empleado, t.mes;


Se me olvidó mencionar que mi versión de mysql en el servidor de despliegue es 5.7. WITH salió para >8.0. Aun así tu consulta me ha ayudado mucho a sacar una consulta que me sirva en producción.

MySQL 5.7 es una versión vieja sin soporte. Deberías actualizarlo a MySQL 8.

lamentablemente no soy responsable de eso. Ya lo propuse pero el cliente no quiso.
